# MySQL query to find occurence of one field into another

Tags: mysql

I want to find all rows form one table where one field is contained into another field.
For example:

[image: sample table]

It seems simple:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', parent_names, '%')
```

I need 1-st and 3-rd row from this query, but the above doesn't work!

Comment: Have you tried to print out the executed request ? Maybe the problem is the "parent_names" or the "name" variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [INSTR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr)

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE instr(parent_names, name) > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to INSTR! Just a little correction:
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE instr(parent_names, name) > 0
, the first name after WHERE was not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

interchange the columns,

```
WHERE parent_names LIKE CONCAT('%', name, '%')
```